# How can I decrease complexity of this part of code?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

This code prints a combination of elements present in an array "pts" (4 elements at a time) in such a way that a particular combination of digits never occurs more than once. Eg. If 1 2 3 4 is printed already then none of its permutations should get printed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pts.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < pts.length; j++) {
        for (int k = j+1; k < pts.length; k++) {    
            for (int l = k+1; l < pts.length; l++) {
                System.out.println(""+pts[i]+" "+pts[j]+" "+pts[k]+" "+pts[l]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can suggest some other approach or can tell me how to reduce this code's complexity. I shall be thankful

Comment: No, this is the best you can do.  No improvement possible, except for readability. Don't add those awful "// k" comments - they only clutter the code without adding information.

Comment: One println command gets executed per thing in the result. How could it possibly be less than this without omitting results?

Comment: You are never actually using any value stored in the ``pts`` array. Is this intended?

Comment: There has got to be another way. I am attempting a question on codechef.com ,but because of this part of code I am getting Time Limit Exceeded.

Comment: Are you sure you want to print 4 elements at a time? Or can you print any permutation of the array? For example `1`, `1 2`, `1 2 3`, `1 2 3 4`. If the latter, you can do it recursively with `O(n)` time complexity

Comment: I somehow think you should be reading elements from the ``pts`` array and finding different ways of rearranging those. You are currently not reading ``pts``, and just showing different ways to rearrange the *indices* of ``pts``.

Comment: Sorry for the little mistake.. I edited the code@Gonzalo

Comment: YeahYeah, I want to print 4 elememts at a time. @Limantara

Comment: If this is a competition, you should definitely mention *what* you are going to do with the results. You're probably not supposed to only *print* them. If there is some computation involved, it's *very* likely that there is a trick that allows you to quickly skip some of the inner loops based on the current values of the outer loops.

Comment: @Marco here is the full description for the problem http://www.codechef.com/OCT14/problems/CHEFSQUA .... and since it is a problem from a live contest , I don't want you  to  give a full description of the logic. just help me with how can i choose combinations of 4 points at a time without considering repeated combinations. here's my solution for the problem http://wikisend.com/download/529854/Square.java

Answer (score 2):

There is not much you can to to improve this.  The output is O(n^4).  The complexity is in the problem statement, not in the implementation of this loop.  You should look into the reason why you want to enumerate all sets (i,j,k,l) with i < j < k < l.

You could avoid to refer to pts.length in every loop.  Depending on what you do in your loop it is not obvious to the compiler that the pts length doesn't change.  The following code has only 1 reference to pts.length and still returns all sets with i < j < k < l < pts.length.

```
for (int l = 0; l < pts.length; l++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < l; k++) {    
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                System.out.println(""+i+" "+j+" "+k+" "+l);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it changes the order of the generated sets, I don't know if it is important.  It is a real small improvement anyway.